# Android: save to internal file

Tags: android, file, android-studio, int, save

I'm using this code trying to save an int to a file and then retrieving it:

```
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try{
        oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir()+"hs.dat")));
        oos.writeInt(hs);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

    TextView txtRecord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRecord);
    try{
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+"hs.dat"));
        hs=ois.readInt();
        txtRecord.setText(getString(R.string.recordStr) +" "+ hs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        txtRecord.setText(getString(R.string.recordStr) +" "+ "0");
    }
```

I always get "0" even when i know the int is not 0, is this not the correct way to do it?

Oim~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the file is still in use.
you need to close it first to release the file so the `ois` can access it.

```java
oos.writeInt(hs);
oos.close(); //--> close the oos
```